# Is there a faster way to do this ForEach and Linq.Any?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, foreach

This run gets me every first appearance of an object with certain conditions.

I run this code 900 times in a application run. It takes 10 minutes for 300.000 objects.
I need to run it with a lot more objects (> 10 million objects) So it'll take a really long time.

This is the best code I could do:

```
string PlayerUrl { get; }

Position Position { get; }

public enum Position
    {
        GK,
        ...
    }

int ChemistryAmount { get; }
```

```
public static List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> GetFirstFieldPlayerStatsForPositionInList(List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions)
{
    List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> fieldPlayerStatsForPositions = new List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition>();
    foreach (IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition fieldPlayerStatsForPosition in auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions)
    {
        if (!fieldPlayerStatsForPositions.Any(cc => fieldPlayerStatsForPosition.FieldPlayerChemistryApplied.FieldPlayer.PlayerUrl == cc.FieldPlayerChemistryApplied.FieldPlayer.PlayerUrl &&
                                                    fieldPlayerStatsForPosition.Position == cc.Position &&
                                                    fieldPlayerStatsForPosition.FieldPlayerChemistryApplied.ChemistryAmount == cc.FieldPlayerChemistryApplied.ChemistryAmount))
        {
            fieldPlayerStatsForPositions.Add(fieldPlayerStatsForPosition);
        }
    }
    return fieldPlayerStatsForPositions;
}
```

I need to make it faster... What should I do?
Is there a faster alternative to a foreach and Linq.Any?

Comment: First is this a string PlayerUrl ? You may want somehow to map it into a type which allows faster comprehension.

Comment: Might help to change fieldPlayerStatsForPositions into a Hashset and just adding your IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition objects to that. That implies implementing GetHashcode and Equals for that type or a Comparer fitting to the if condition in your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm time complexity is O(n^2). In order to speed it up you need to use a different container.
You can reduce it to O(n) using a HashSet and a custom IEqualityComparer:

```
public class FieldPlayerStatsForPositionComparer : IEqualityComparer<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> {
    public bool Equals(IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition x, IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition y) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType())
            return false;
        return x.PlayerUrl == y.PlayerUrl && x.Position == y.Position && x.ChemistryAmount == y.ChemistryAmount;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition obj) {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.PlayerUrl, (int)obj.Position, obj.ChemistryAmount);
    }
}

public static List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> GetFirstFieldPlayerStatsForPositionInList(List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions)
{
    var fieldPlayerStatsForPositions = new HashSet<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition>(auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions, new FieldPlayerStatsForPositionComparer());
    return fieldPlayerStatsForPositions.ToList();
}
```

Please note that hash set does not keep the original order of items. If original order is a must for you, please leave a comment.

*UPDATE*

As Joel Coehoorn pointed out, to avoid double memory allocation you can use IEnumerable instead of creating a new List:

```
public static IEnumerable<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> GetFirstFieldPlayerStatsForPositionInList(IEnumerable<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions) {
    return auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions.Distinct(new FieldPlayerStatsForPositionComparer());
}
```

The .Distinct() method also keeps the original order of the items.

Or alternatively, you can return the HashSet itself or ICollection interface:

```
public static ICollection<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> GetFirstFieldPlayerStatsForPositionInList(IEnumerable<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions) {
    return new HashSet<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition>(auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions, new FieldPlayerStatsForPositionComparer());
}
```

I would also suggest to use `BenchmarkDotNet` NuGet package to test runtime performance and memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use at least .NET 6 :

All you function seems to be doing is remove elements that are duplicate by the 3 properties

You can replace you function by a [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0):

```cs
public static List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> GetFirstFieldPlayerStatsForPositionInList(List<IFieldPlayerStatsForPosition> auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions)
{
    return auxFieldPlayerStatsForPositions.DistinctBy(p => new 
    { 
        p.FieldPlayerChemistryApplied.FieldPlayer.PlayerUrl,
        p.Position,
        p.FieldPlayerChemistryApplied.ChemistryAmount
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I'll compare and tell which one is faster

Comment: The author does make an emphasis on performance and Linq methods would create a lot of overhead. Using a custom equality comparer with hash code combining is much faster.

Comment: @theemee The main reason the OPs code perform poorly is algorithmic complexity. So while this solution might be slower than a custom equality comparer, tit should still be much faster than the original. This has the advantage of being easier to read, and might be *good enough*.

Comment: @JonasH the author states that he intends to run the algorithm against 10 million objects. This solution will allocate additional memory for every object in the list for those temporary comparison objects which will put a massive strain on the garbage collector. Check out my solution above.

Comment: @theemee I have already upvoted your answer. But I consider this to be a decent alternative, even if it trades some memory/performance for simpler code. And even if it allocates 10M objects that does not mean it will have a noticeable runtime impact. Short lived objects are actually not that bad for the GC, since collection time scale with the number of alive objects, not dead ones. Tho high allocation rates can cause more collections. In the end you need to consider the context when optimizing, is it code that will be run by millions of users? or one or two in a short project?

Comment: DistinctBy can also take a custom IEqualityComparer, but it would be less relevant in this case